# pyspark files loading errors shows

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to load file to my spark and here is my code.

```
lines = sc.textFile('file:///Users/zhangqing198573/data/weblog_lab.csv')
```

and the error shows

> 17/03/04 22:16:32 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values
>   in memory (estimated size 127.4 KB, free 127.4 KB) 17/03/04 22:16:32
>   INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory
>   (estimated size 13.9 KB, free 141.3 KB) 17/03/04 22:16:32 INFO
>   BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on
>   localhost:53383 (size: 13.9 KB, free: 511.1 MB) 17/03/04 22:16:32 INFO
>   SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from textFile at
>   NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2.

I dont know whats wrong

Comment: What error do you see in these log mesages?

Comment: According to the log you provided it seems like everything is fine. try to execute `lines.count()` or `lines.take(10)` and see the result (you might need to prefix `print` to those commands in order to print the results to stdout